# SSH into local network machine while connected to a VPN in Linux

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, vpn

Is it possible and how could I go about being able to ssh into a local network machine while said local network machine is connected to a VPN.

I also found no questions or suggestions regarding this, thus the reason for this question. The hosts involved are:

- Laptop, my PC, not connected to VPN.
- Raspberry Pi, local network machine, connected to vpn.

I am able to access Samba shares from the Raspberry Pi. However, I am not able to ssh into the Pi while it is connected. Of course, I am able to connect to it when it is not connected.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does "no connected to vpn" mean?  Not connected? or Now connected?

Comment: What are samba shared from the pi?  is the pi a client accessing a samba server?  Or is the pi running samba and you're accessoing the pi's samba shares?

Comment: if it's the case that a computer loses the IP that it had before connecting to the VPN, and if the VPN server is doing NAPT then you could set up port forwarding as one would do with a NAPT router, but for the VPN server. That may depend on what software the VPN server is running.. how to configure that. i'm not expert though.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, the laptop and the pc belong to the same LAN. Hence you should be able to connect to the RPI without any problem, even when it is connected to the VPN.

If you cannot, it is because, for some reason, the route to your local LAN has been somehow `lost`. The route I am taking about is:

```
 192.168.73.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.73.54  metric 1
```

or some such thing. You should check that, connecting to the VPN, you have not lost such route. The most common cause for this to happen is that the local and the remote (*i.e.*, the one to which the VPN server belongs) are the same, for instance they are both `192.168.1.0/24`. In this case you will lose connectivity. The second most common cause for connectivity loss is the local subnet is the same as that of the VPN tunnel.

You should make sure that the local subnet, the remote subnet, and the tunnel subnet are all distinct. If they are, you will be able to connect to the RPI as easily as if it were not connected to the VPN, from within the same LAN.

If instead your laptop belongs to a different LAN, then a different answer is needed. But we'll cross that bridge when we get there.